# Flutter: Is it possible to automatically switch screens without pressing a button?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a quiz application that moves to the next page when a button is pressed. However, I would like to delete the button and replace it with a function that automatically advances to the next page after being scored when you manually enter an answer. How can I change the press: () code to do this?

```
class Option extends StatelessWidget {
  const Option({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.index,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final int index;
  final VoidCallback press;








class QuestionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuestionCard({
    Key ?key,
    required this.question,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Question question;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _controller = Get.put(QuestionController());
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          ...List.generate(
            question.options.length,
                (index) => Option(
              index: index,
              text: question.options[index],
              press: () => _controller.checkAns(question, index),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}





void checkAns(Question question, String selectedIndex) {
    _isAnswered = true;
    _correctAns = question.options;
    _selectedAns = selectedIndex;

    if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) _numOfCorrectAns++;
    update();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (_questionNumber.value != _questions.length) {
        _isAnswered = false;
        _pageController.nextPage(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.ease);
      } else {
        Get.off(ScoreScreen());
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can call `Get.off(ScoreScreen());` whenever you want. It doesn't have to be in the body of a button's handler method.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should - first - deepen the logic behind this choice: when exactly do you expect the app to advance to the next page / question?

Say your user just finished typing, how can you recognize that he finished to answer? Maybe he just paused to, say, think a little more.

I'd personally choose to add a `textInputAction: TextInputAction.done` onto the last form in the current page. Although this wouldn't work on Web or Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it with a gesture detector (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html), or you can use navigator.push to a new screen (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.